# What is the type of argument "replacement" in gensub() of GAWK?

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

[The prototype of the function `gensub()` in GAWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is

```
gensub(regexp, replacement, how [, target])
```

1. According to my observations from examples,

   - `regexp` is a regular expression enclosed in slashes
   - I saw in examples a quoted string is provided to `replacement` (see the example below).

     But it can contain back-references to groups in the matched substring (see the example below), which seems to
     me that the type of `replacement` is a regular expression, and that the quoted string provided to `replacement` is coerced into a regular expression.

     Now I am
     confused: what is the type of `replacement`, a string, or a regular
     expression?
2. Can I give a regular expression enclosed in slashes to
   `replacement`?

   E.g., from the same link:

   ```
   $ gawk '
   > BEGIN {
   >      a = "abc def"
   >      b = gensub(/(.+) (.+)/, "\\2 \\1", "g", a)
   >      print b
   > }'
   -| def abc
   ```

   Can I replace `b = gensub(/(.+) (.+)/, "\\2 \\1", "g", a)` with `b =
   gensub(/(.+) (.+)/, /\2 \1/, "g", a)`?

   Btw, what does `-| def abc` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily, replacement is a string with a limited set of metacharacters.

If using a regex as the replacement compiles, then it may be accepted; I'd hate to have to work out what it does.

The `-| def abc` is mostly just the output from the preceding (illustrative) command. The role of the `-|` is explained in [typographical conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conventions.html#Conventions) as a glyph marking output to standard output; most of the other example outputs have that marker before the output.  It is not a part of the `awk` command, anyway.  The `awk` command would generate `def abc`.

> What characters are treated specially?

The manual says (at `gensub()`):

> This is done by using parentheses in the regexp to mark the components and then specifying ‘\N’ in the replacement text, where N is a digit from 1 to 9.

It also mentions 'more than `sub` and `gsub` provide), so looking at `gsub()`, it says:

> As in `sub()`, the characters ‘&’ and ‘\’ are special

and `sub()` says:

> If the special character ‘&’ appears in replacement, it stands for the precise substring that was matched by regexp. … The effect of this special character (‘&’) can be turned off by putting a backslash before it in the string. As usual, to insert one backslash in the string, you must write two backslashes. Therefore, write ‘\&’ in a string constant to include a literal ‘&’ in the replacement.

Comment: Thanks. "replacement is a string with a limited set of metacharacters."  Backreferences to captured groups can appear in `replacement`, but `replacement` is specified as a quoted string. Is the type  of `replacement` a string, a regular expression, or something else?

Comment: It is a string, like I said. A few characters in the string are treated specially but otherwise it is a string.

Comment: what characters are treated specially?